# How do I prevent date entry of duplicate records with in an object?

Tags: validation

I have an opportunity product and I want that everytime some add a new product they cannot choose same ad position selected previously within same date range.

Unique ad position for same date ranges  for same product.

[image]

Comment: can you post your approach whatever you have tried so far

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are comfortable writing custom Apex, the appropriate solution here would be to write a trigger that would run BEFORE insert and update on the Opportunity Product sobject.

For each item being inserted / updated (remember to bulkify), gather the Ad Positions into a set and then perform a query to check whether any other Opportunity Products exist with an Ad Position matching the value in that set.

If one does, use the [addError method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError_2) to prevent saving the record.

I'm not sure there's any way to do this that doesn't involve custom Apex so this will be your best bet.